# Will images look different from the iPhone Simulator to an actual iDevice?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, cocos2d-iphone, ipod-touch

Images that I add to the layer in Cocos2d look pixelated around the edges of the image (i.e. a hillside, the rounded part of the hill, where the sky and the hill meet). I don't know if it's the image quality, or just because the graphics processor on my 'older' MacBook Pro is not as advanced as the iPhone 4 or iPod Touch 4 or iPad 2. Is it because of that?

Comment: Odd edge-effects in OpenGL (which Cocos2D uses) are often due to the way the interpolation works. The short story is that you can often fix it by adding a 1px transparent border around the problematic edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran into an instance where a large resolution image was being used in the context of a locally packaged HTML file in a `UIWebView`.  The image looked fine in the simulator, but when ran on a hardware device, a bug was exposed in the rendering engine where it would invert the colors.  [Here's](http://jira.openmindlab.com/browse/MEDIA-72) a bug report as an example of this.  The solution was to scale the image down a bit in photo editing application.

While an extreme corner case, this is an example of the simulator not quite living up to how things will work on a hardware device.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator usually does a pretty good job representing what the final image will look like. For the image quality on a normal computer to be worse than that of an iPhone for it to make a large enough difference, your MacBook Pro has to be really bad. So I doubt it.

However, if you really want to make sure, the best way to check would be to transfer the image you are using to another machine to see if it still looks pixelated. If it does, its a problem with your image.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could upload the image and give me a link so that I could tell you if it's pixelated!